# Can't play mp4 files in Edubuntu 12.04

Tags: multimedia, edubuntu, mp4

I have installed new Edubuntu 12.04 and unfortunately my mp4 files are not running.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! You may want to specify what software you are trying to run the mp4 files with and whether you have any error messages appearing so others find it easier to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Type this command in terminal (press ctrl+alt+t to open)

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

It will install all media codecs which are necessary for playing media files.